# set up socks proxy at home to use away from home

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, socks

I have a linux box at home. I know I can set up a proxy on a current computer by opening up terminal and typing `ssh -D PORT USER@SERVER` and then enter in the proxy and port in a browser. HOWEVER - I do not have Terminal permissions my current computer.

I have DynDNS set up, and port forwards to my linux box. I logged in remotely and then set up a SOCKS proxy to another computer.

Setup like this:

```
HOMECOMPUTER$ ssh -D 8080 USER2@OTHERSERVER
OTHERSERVER$
```

I should be able to enter `HOMECOMPUTER dyndns` url as the SOCKS server and `8080` as the port, correct?

It doesn't work; pages don't load. What's wrong?

If this question wasn't clear enough, sorry :( I'll change it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a bind_address is not provided with the -D option, then the default is to bind only to localhost. You can have the SOCKS server listen on all interfaces by binding it to the IP address 0.0.0.0:

```
ssh -D 0.0.0.0:8080 user2@serverB
```

You should then be able to enter `HOMECOMPUTER dyndns` as the SOCKS server and 8080 as the port.

Comment: where `1.2.3.4` is `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: yeah buddayyy this works! enjoy the rep!